# setTimeout in a loop only affect the last element

Tags: jquery

My goal is to change the `background-color` of each divs every 100 milliseconds.. Currently it only change the background of the last element, this is my current approach:

HTML

```
<nav>
    <div class="icon-a">1</div>
    <div class="icon-b">2</div>
    <div class="icon-c">3</div>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
var delay=100;
$('nav [class^=icon-]').each(function(counter){
    //counter will start from 0..
    timeout = delay * (counter + 1);
    selector = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
         selector.toggleClass('colorHigh');
    }, timeout);
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k57425z6/)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are defining a global variable, use the `var` keyword:

```
var selector = $(this);
```

Comment: an `var` for timeout also, otherwise it will change color of all at the same time.

Comment: @Mritunjay No, that won't happen. But, yes, global variables are _bad_.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the global variable `selector` so you are always changing the same variable.

```
var delay=100;
$('nav [class^=icon-]').each(function(counter){
    //counter will start from 0..
    var selector;
    timeout = delay * (counter + 1);
    selector = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
         selector.toggleClass('colorHigh');
    }, timeout);
});
```

For me your code works like this.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k57425z6/1/)